# Uncaught TypeError: $(…).dataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i Have Facing this problem how can to resolve this problem

my code is

```
function dataset(databind) {
    $('#Div_BalanceLeave')
        .html('<table  cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable" id="sample_1" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" ></table>');

    $('#sample_1')
        .DataTable({
            "ajax": "data.json",
            "data": databind,
            "columns": [
               { "title": "Name" }
              ,{ "title": "EmpCode" }
              ,{ "title": "Balance" }
              ,{ "title": "ApplyFrom" }
              ,{ "title": "LeaveType" }
              ,{ "title": "UpdateDate" }
            ]
        });

    $('#sample_1')
        .DataTable()
        .destroy();
}
```

Comment: There is no `.dataTable()` in the script. Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the *actual* code

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests your DataTables script files are not being referenced correctly.

Use Chrome Dev tools or similar to see if they are loaded. Even just view the page source.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have added js file for jquery datatable
2. Make sure you are calling `dataset` function on document ready.

One more thing in your dataset function you are initializing datatable and immediately you are destroying datatable that does not make sense.